# Regular expression for non-english characters

Tags: r, regex, special-characters

I need to check if some strings contain any non-English characters.

```
x = c('KÃ¤lt', 'normal', 'normal with, punctuation ~-+!', 'normal with number 1234')
grep(pattern = ??, x) # Expected output:1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `[^[:ascii:]]` PCRE regex:

```
x = c('KÃ¤lt', 'normal', 'normal with, punctuation ~-+!', 'normal with number 1234')
grep(pattern = "[^[:ascii:]]", x, perl=TRUE) 
grep(pattern = "[^[:ascii:]]", x, value=TRUE, perl=TRUE)
```

Ouput:

```
[1] 1
[1] "KÃ¤lt"
```

See the [R demo](http://ideone.com/vxav28)

Comment: Works as expected! Thanks Wiktor!

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the answer that's already been provided

**To check for non-ASCII**

```r
x = c('KÃ¤lt', 'normal', 'normal punctuation ~-+!', 'normal number 1234')
grep(pattern = "[^[:ascii:]]", x, perl=TRUE) 
grep(pattern = "[^[:ascii:]]", x, value=TRUE, perl=TRUE)
```

**To check for non-unicode**

```r
x = c('KÃ¤lt', 'normal', 'normal punctuation ~-+!', 'normal number 1234')
grep(pattern = "[^\u0001-\u007F]+", x, perl=TRUE) 
grep(pattern = "[^\u0001-\u007F]+", x, value=TRUE, perl=TRUE)
```

**you can also use the `stringi` package** to determine if a string is ASCII

```r
x = c('KÃ¤lt', 'normal', 'normal punctuation ~-+!', 'normal number 1234')
stringi::stri_enc_isascii(x)
```